# Simplifying a boolean expression

Tags: logic

I need to prove:

`XY + ~XZ + YZ = XY + ~XZ`

I cannot think how to do this.

I have tried factorising, but I just don't know of any rule that removes one of the terms like above.

I start with the LHS, naturally:

All I can do is get to:

`Y(X+Z) + ~XZ`

Comment: Since there are only three variables, writing out the two truth tables will do just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, answer is as follows, unsure if there's an easier method:

$XY+X'Z+YZ  \\
XY+X'Z+YZ(1)  \\
XY+X'Z+YZ(X+X')  \\
XY+X'Z+XYZ+X'YZ  \\
(XY+XYZ)+(X'Z+X'YZ)  \\
XY(1+Z)+X'Z(1+Y)  \\
XY(1)+X'Z(1)  \\
XY+X'Z$

Answer (score 2):

Here is an ugly solution, found with the Karnaugh table and the equation : A = A.B + A./B

XY + /XZ + YZ

= X.Y.Z + X.Y./Z + /X.Y.Z + /X./Y.Z + X.Y.Z + /X.Y.Z

(removing two redundant terms)

= X.Y.Z + X.Y./Z + /X./Y.Z + /X.Y.Z

= XY + /X.Z

Comment: I'm afraid this won't be a valid solution, I've been staring at this blankly for some time now. The question simply asks to use 'Boolean algebra' to prove ... Anyother ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple argument:

To prove $XY+X'Z+YZ = XY+X'Z$, we only need to show that 
$$(YZ = 1) \Rightarrow (XY + X'Z = 1)$$
which is obvious, because
$$(YZ = 1) \Rightarrow (Y = 1 \land Z = 1) \Rightarrow (XY + X'Z = 1)$$
no matter whether $X = 0$ or $X = 1$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $XY+X'Z = Y + Z$.

Intuitively, because if X is true, then the second term must be false, which means whether the entire expression is true depends on $Y$. Likewise for $Z$. Then we get:

$Y + Z + YZ$

This statement is true when $X$ is true, or when $Y$ is true, or when both are true. But that is redundant, and we can reduce to:

$Y + Z$

Recall from earlier that we established that $XY+X'Z = Y + Z$. Thus we get:

$XY + X'Z$